# Socket.io And Next.js `net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

Tags: python, reactjs, next.js, uvicorn, socket.io-client

I'm implemented Socket.io Server by UVICORN on windows 10 OS and implemented Client Side by Next.js and Typescript.

But when i tried to connect to the socket.io server, i have below errors!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this when happing the `CORS` error happing in Brave browser.

- turn off Brave Shield
- install CORS Unblocker extension